# about android sending get request

Tags: android, http, request

*Here I have a problem with getting request in Android.
I have run server program using webapp2 on my PC and I succeeded in sending request from itself to the server program. 
However, when I tried to send request from my phone, it seems the program always jump the catch(Exception e) part. The three Log.e() works fine since I could see all of them in the log records. Can anyone tell me what might go wrong here? Is it the fire wall that my PC used to block the request? Thanks in advance.
PS: the variable resultString is the result I get from voice recognition.*

```
try{
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("http://192.168.1.100:9080/");
            buf.append("?");
            buf.append("content1="+URLEncoder.encode(resultString,"UTF-8"));
            //buf.append(resultString);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, buf, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            URL url = new URL(buf.toString());
            Log.e("check1","url_transformation works ok");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            Log.e("check2","open connection works ok");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            Log.e("check3","set get works ok");

            if(conn.getResponseCode()==200){
                Log.e("check4","get works");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GET works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else 
                {
                Log.e("check5","get fails");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GET fails", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "other problems occur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:872)
03-05 20:47:19.486: W/System.err(16066):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:77)

I think the exception log is as described as above. So what's wrong here?

I have tried AsyncTask as some of you suggested. 
The code is as belowed:

```
private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, String> {



    private String URL = "http://192.168.1.100:9080/" + "?" +"content1="+resultString;
    //buf.append("content1="+URLEncoder.encode(resultString,"UTF-8"));
    AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
    //Log.e("check", "succeed");
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... param) {

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
        //Log.e("check1","succeed");
        Log.e("url",URL);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        try {
            Log.e("check3","succeed");
            return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);


        } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("check4","succeed");


        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("check5","succeed");


        }
        Log.e("check6","succeed");//to this point
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (null != mClient)
            mClient.close();
        //Log.e("check6","succeed");
        mTextView.setText(result);

    }
}
```

03-06 14:57:07.117: W/System.err(12451): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.1.100:9080 timed out
03-06 14:57:07.137: W/System.err(12451):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
03-06 14:57:07.137: W/System.err(12451):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)

the Log shows that there is an **IOException** in my codes and the value of mClient will eventually be null.I have looked online for the same situation and it seems this occurs when data takes too much time to respond that is requested. And many of the answers suggested I should reset Timeout and allow more time for the request to be sent. But I don't really understand where to put the reset codes in my situation. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: please dont use bold text to descripe your problem...

Comment: You should try to capture the exception and show us what it says. By the way, did you add the android.permission.INTERNET permission to the manifest?

Comment: Yes I do add the permission since the recognition part needs it too. By capturing exception what do you mean? print out the content of e?

Answer (score 1):

NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when you try to perform network operations on the main/UI thread. This is not allowed in Android. Instead, you need to perform network operations in a background thread. You can do this using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can put this on `onCreate()`, but the best option is to use `AsyncTask`.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy threadPolicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(threadPolicy);
```